# Solve a complex equation in R

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve

$x=1+w^x + w^{2x}$

Where $w$ ,$w^2$ are cube roots of the unit and $x$ is pure real number
My attempt :-

let $w = \cos(120) + i \sin(120)$

Then

$x = 1+\cos(120x) + \cos(240x) + [\sin(120x) + \sin(240x) ]i$

$x = 1+\cos(120x) + \cos(240x) $

And

$\sin(120x) + \sin(240x) = 0$

I can solve the second equation i fo not know how can i solve the first one ?

Comment: $x=3$ is a solution

Comment: How can i get it ? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: If you mean $120$ to be degrees you should include the degree sign, which you can get with ^\circ.  Otherwise you can use $\frac 23\pi$.  Also putting a backslash before common functions gives the correct font and spacing, so \sin x gives $\sin x$ instead of sin x which gives $sin x$

Answer (score 1):

$x=1+w^x+w^{2x}\implies x(w^x-1)=w^{3x}-1=0\implies x=0 $ or  $w^x=1$.

But $x=0$ is not a solution, so $x=1+w^x+w^{2x}=1+1+1=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $w^2=1/w$, we have
$$x=1+w^x+\frac{1}{w^x} \iff xw^x=1+w^x+w^{2x}=x$$
Now $x=0$ isn't a solution so $w^x=1 \implies x=3k$, where $k$ is a non-zero integer,
but this means $3k=1+1+1 \implies k=1, x=3$